# Animation not working properly (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift

The following block is my code. I don't know why, but the animation delay is not working at all. No matter how many seconds I increase it to be..

```
func changeLabelisTapped(_ textLabel: UILabel, tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    for i in 0...2{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: Double(i)+2, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: ({
            self.subArray.remove(at: 0)
            self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)])
        }), completion: nil)
    }
    let tempArray = Array(self.tabledData[3...self.tabledData.count-1])
    print(tempArray.count)
    for j in 0...2{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 2, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: ({
            let newElement = tempArray[j]
            self.subArray.append(newElement)
            self.collectionView.insertItems(at:[IndexPath(row: j, section: 0)])
        }), completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UIView animations do not queue. So everytime you process it through a loop the next animations cancels the one before and you do not see the delay. Instead of using a loop you should chain your animations so that the next one is called in the completion handler. Remove the loop and call the next animation to occur in the completion handler.

```
    var currentCount = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 2, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: ({
        let newElement = tempArray[self.currentCount]
        self.subArray.append(newElement)
        self.collectionView.insertItems(at:[IndexPath(row: self.currentCount, section: 0)])
    }), completion: { _ in
       //next animation follows here 
       self.currentCount += 1
         UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 2, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: ({
        let newElement = tempArray[self.currentCount]
        self.subArray.append(newElement)
        self.collectionView.insertItems(at:[IndexPath(row: self.currentCount, section: 0)])
    }), completion: { _ in //and so on

     })

    })
```

If you want to cleanly control how many times the animation should happen, then you can use a recursive callback in the completion handler. To make this work, move your animation code into a function.

```
    let loopCount = 3

    var currentCount = 0

    func animateMyLabel() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 2, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: ({
        let newElement = tempArray[self.currentCount]
        self.subArray.append(newElement)
        self.collectionView.insertItems(at:[IndexPath(row: self.currentCount, section: 0)])
    }), completion: { _ in 
        if self.currentCount < self.loopCount {
          self.currentCount += 1
          //call the animation again
          self.animateMyLabel()
        }

    })

    }
```

**EDIT**

Having faced a similar delay issue in a current project I am doing, I have learnt a new way to force a delay if it is not working as expected which might help anyone that comes across this question. The solution is to force a delay in the completion handler just before the next animation should occur by adding delay(seconds: n) { } where n is the number of seconds the delay should happen for. So to add this to the problem:

```
   let loopCount = 3

    var currentCount = 0

    func animateMyLabel() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 2, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: ({
        let newElement = tempArray[self.currentCount]
        self.subArray.append(newElement)
        self.collectionView.insertItems(at:[IndexPath(row: self.currentCount, section: 0)])
    }), completion: { _ in 
        if self.currentCount < self.loopCount {
          //add the delay here
          delay(seconds: 2) {
          self.currentCount += 1
          //call the animation again
          self.animateMyLabel()
          }
        }

    })

    }
```

Furthermore, although animations do not queue, it is possible to use a loop for an animation provided the next animation in sequence has a delay which allows the previous animation to complete.

Comment: It still does not work.. I increased the delay to 10 seconds.. The animation takes the same time to finish. But thanks for answering though!

Comment: You removed the for loop and it still does not work?

Comment: Yup, i tried the second block of yours.. It does not work... :(.. I watched a tutorial on animation... The video shows that you do not need completion box to increase the delay.. You just have to increase the delayCounter and the cells will layout accordingly.. So, i don't know if it is just the insertion and deletion cells problems

Comment: Yes. They did not use a completion block because the delay is 2 seconds which allows the former animation time to complete, I missed that although it not always a good idea. I think I can see a typo in your code. I can see extra round brackets in your UIView animation starting from the parameter animations. Can you correct it like this and see if it works UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 2, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                //your code
            }, completion: nil)

Comment: really appreciate your help (((: ... but nope.. i copied your code and paste it inside with some edition, but it still does not work... The thing is that, i can increase the duration of the animation and the animation will have that duration, but when i increase the delay, it does not have any effect at all.